# Wordpress (ACF) function does not return a value

Tags: php, wordpress, function, return-value, advanced-custom-fields

I am able to parse the data through the variable no problem, but the HTML output for my echo is not being wrapped properly.

```
<?
    if( get_field('pre_video_set_label_name') ) {
        echo "<h3>" . the_field('pre_video_set_label_name') . "</h3>";
    } else {
        echo "<h3>Post-Event Video</h3>";
    }
?>
```

If my input for `pre_video_set_label_name` is "Test" then the HTML output becomes:

```
Test<h3></h3>
```

My expected output would be:

```
<h3>Test</h3>
```

But I'm not getting these results.

Nothing seems to wrap, and I've been having this problem a lot lately. Is there an error in my way of thinking with this?

Comment: did you check if the_field('pre_video_set_label_name') is actually returning a valid value ?

Comment: Because `the_field()` **prints** the data and **doesn't return it**

Comment: You can get the value of `the_field('pre_video_set_label_name')` in separate variable and echo inside h3 tag

Comment: @StudentX Yes, as stated it returns a value but isn't wrapped. @Rizier123 hmm, didn't consider that. How can I return this value? `return` instead of `echo`?

Comment: Use: `get_field()`. Always check the docs: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/ , http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: @Exception I was hoping to not have to do that lol. I wanted to figure out how to do this correctly through an operator like echo.

Comment: `the_field()` is not a wordpress function are you using this or something similar advancedcustomfields.com ?

Comment: @AlexAndrei He most probably uses ACF

Comment: To clear up some confusion, this has happened with my own variables using echo as well. I am using ACF for this project, but the concept expands out to my other custom plugins / functions. I've had similar issues so I didn't know if it was a flaw in my knowledge of PHP or what. :)

Comment: If the_field prints the data instead of returning it, then you can do something like this : echo '<h3>'; the_field('pre_video_set_label_name''); echo '</h3>';

Comment: @Rizier123 Thank you for the post cleanup!

Comment: @StudentX ah, this may be what I need to do for variables outside of ACF too. Thank you so much, will test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use [wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/) / ([ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/)) functions, always check if they **display** or **return** the value.

#### Function, which *displays* the value:

```
function displayX(){
    echo "data";
}
```

If you want to call this function, you *won't* need a `echo` to display the data, just call it, e.g.

```
displayX();  //output: data
```

**Note:** The function, won't return the data. But even if it doesn't have an explicit return statement and also won't return the data, [it still will return something (NULL)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php).

#### Function, which *returns* the value:

```
function returnX(){
    return "data";
}
```

If you want to call this function, you *will* need a `echo` to display the data, just call it, e.g.

```
echo returnX();  //output: data
```

**Note:** This function will return the data and doesn't display it by its own.

#### Different behaviour

You will notice some differences, when you use functions which display or return a value.

1. Assignment

   1.1 Function, which *displays* the value:

   ```
   $variable = displayX();
   ```

   **Note:** `$variable`, will be assigned with `NULL` and the line above *will* output `data`.

   1.2  Function, which *returns* the value:

   ```
   $variable = returnX();
   ```

   **Note:** `$variable`, will be assigned with `data` and the line above *won't* output anything.
2. Concatenation

   2.1 Function, which *displays* the value:

   ```
   echo "string start " . displayX() . " string end";
   ```

   **Note:** You will concatenate `NULL` here, since this function will return this value. The function *will* display `data` first, before you see the concatenated string.

   2.2  Function, which *returns* the value:

   ```
   $variable = returnX();
   ```

   **Note:** You will concatenate `data` here, since this function will return this value. The function *won't* display anything first, before you see the concatenated string.
3. Printing

   3.1 Function, which *displays* the value:

   ```
   displayX();
   ```

   **Note:** This code *will* output `data`.

   3.2  Function, which *returns* the value:

   ```
   returnX();
   ```

   **Note:** This code won't display anything.

---

So in your current example you use [`the_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/), which **displays** the data. But if you want to concatenate it, you will need the data **returned**, means use [`get_filed()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/), which simply will **return** the data.

There is also a easy way to check what a function returns. Just do: `var_dump(functionCall());` and you will see what the function returns.

Comment: I've reselected this to be the answer. The informative post and teachings you provided go above and beyond. Thank you for your time and insight!

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [`get_field()`](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) with `echo`, since `the_field()` already echoes the meta field:

```
echo "<h3>" . get_field('pre_video_set_label_name') . "</h3>";
```

`get_field()` returns the meta value, rather than echoing it.

Comment: This works! Will accept as answer. This has happened with my own custom variables too, the variable never get's wrapped. What can I do differently?

Comment: It happens to custom *variables* or custom *functions*? `get_field()` is a function. This shouldn't be happening with variables...

Comment: @Rizier123 , Please post a comment if you have info to add. Edits to answers aren't the place for that.

Comment: If I create a variable `$test = "Hello, world!"` and then echo it with `echo "<h1>" . $test . "</h1>";` i've had the same issues. No clue why.

Comment: @rnevius Just wanted to improve your answer, but if you don't like it np.