# How do I replace the string value in php in this case?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm not a PHP guy so no idea so how to do it, but tried something as given below.

Requirement:

```
<link href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
```

Currently gives me this output:

```
<link href="http://example.com/au/">
```

I need to change a part of URL at runtime using regular expression or any string replace function.

Something like this:

```
<link href="<?php echo str_replace("/au/","/uk/","<?php the_permalink(); ?>"); ?>"/>
```

I thought this would work, but instead it gives me this:

```
<link href="http://example.com/uk/"/>
```

Please advise what would be the correct solution.

Comment: easy : <link href="<?= str_replace("au","uk", the_permalink());?>"/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't need PHP tags when you are already in PHP tags. Second the function [`the_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/) doesn't actually return the value which you want, it just displays it (See this post to see more about the difference of displaying and returing: [Wordpress (ACF) function does not return a value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32975863/3933332))

So you probably want to use [`get_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) here, since this function returns the value you want. Then you can also use it almost as you already tried:

```
<link href="<?php echo str_replace("/au/","/uk/", get_permalink()); ?>"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of manually doing a string replacement each time you need this, I recommend adding the following filter to *functions.php*:

```
function au_to_uk_permalink($url) {
    return str_replace('/au/','/uk/', $url);
}
add_filter('the_permalink', 'au_to_uk_permalink');
```

You can now use `the_permalink()` function as usual in your templates, and the string substitution will automatically be applied:

```
<?php the_permalink(); ?>
<!-- Outputs: http://example.com/uk/some-post/ -->
```

Read more about [`the_permalink` filter in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_permalink).

Comment: Thanks I'll try this.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<?php
  $link = get_permalink();
  $link = str_replace("/au","/uk",$link);
?>
<link href="<?php echo $link; ?>" />
```